# Illustrator/Photoshop: how to get path points' coordinates?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

[image: How to get black points' coordinates?]

Hi everybody

In the picture there is a line with black points. While I know how to get the anchor points coordinates with the mouse cursor, I would love to know how to get the information of the black points' coordinates.
An additional goal would be to export the points' coordinates into a text file.

Can someone help me?

Cheers and thanks for any hints,
Matt

Comment: The info window shows the cursor location. Beyond that you'd need to either expand the circles thus giving them each anchor points or add anchor points yourself.

Comment: I think you need to be *specific* on the app. Each will have it's own method if possible. Since your screenshot is AI... can you expand the blend?

Answer (score 3):

To help with your *additional goal*:

I am working on a project that has this requirement, so I put together a small Illustrator script that exports a JSON file including points in each layer. It's pretty basic right now, but you may find it useful: https://github.com/elcontraption/illustrator-point-coordinate-exporter

As of now it only works with polygons, and there is no differentiation between shapes in a layer. It will output an object named for each layer, containing an array of all points within that layer.

Comment: Update: each path in a layer gets its own array of points.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your Path
2. Object > Path > Outline Stroke

Now all the circles should be Path which you can easily select with the direct selection tool (the white Arrow) getting the exact coordinates for their center points.

---

Bonus Points: You can also doubling click on the line to go into isolation mode, making it easier to select a single circle. If you have one select you can cut it and if you do Edit > Insert at original position you can isolate it for good.